# Odd question selection in the "About" section of the site

Tags: support, tour

I'm currently seeing this question in the [About](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/about) page on them main site:

> [image]

This doesn't strike me as a particularly good, on-topic question here, and might need to be looked into.

<sub>If I'm missing something in Christian folklore about unicorns and daisies, please forgive my ignorance.</sub>

Comment: Hmmm. You might have a point. I think there is a mechanism to customize this...

Comment: There's some info about that [on MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163947/what-determines-the-questions-available-for-selection-in-the-about-page). Doesn't seem entirely straightforward.

Answer (score 5):

This is going to be harder than you'd think to fix!

So in order to use a live there are a bunch of qualifications that the question/answer candidate must fulfill including the question and at least two answers being of a certain limited length and not having any special formatting. Using the DE, I see there is currently exactly one question on our entire site meeting those qualifications. Unfortunately since the qualifying answers are neither the accepted or even the several top voted answers, this leaves us with a possibly heretical set of answers getting pulled.

So at the moment, it's Unicorns or heretics. Frankly I think we're better off with the unicorns and daisies for the moment.

The ultimate solution seems to be to conjure up a special question and set of answers that the community agrees on as being roughly representative of both our subject matter and site guidelines without breaking any of the qualifying rules.

Comment: Heretics or unicorns, unicorns or heretics, quite the conundrum :-) Do you want to "retarget" this question into a discussion about what to put up there? (Would probably be better if someone involved in the site started that question though.)

Comment: I thought we *had* a custom question in there. something about nails

Comment: @waxeagle I kind of thought we had one too, I seem to remember having this conversation. But I don't know what it was. Mat I'm find with repurposing this post to drum up a new one, but lets see if we can identify what happened to our earlier one first.

Comment: Are we able to suggest new questions? I'd be surprised if we couldn't find one. Especially when that question is so opinion-based!

Comment: @curiousdannii Yes you can suggest a new pick, but it has to meet the size and formatting criteria.

Comment: @Caleb and to clarify it has to be a real question that's been asked before, rather than making one up for this purpose?

Comment: @curousdannii It has to be a real question that exists on the main site. We could conceivably contrive one for the purpose and cheat by rigging the ask, answer, and votes so it would qualify.